# How to link with libm.so and libdl.so with my bazel project?

Tags: c++, dependencies, bazel

I'm trying to use some cos/sin function and dlopen/sym function inside my c program, and have this in my "BUILD" file:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "hello-dl",
    srcs = ["hello-dl.cc"],
    deps = ["dl"],
)
```

My source file is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
int main(){
    void * handle = dlopen("hello-greet", RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!handle) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    void (*f)() = (void (*)()) dlsym(handle, "f");
    char* error = dlerror();
    if (error != NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", error);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    f();
    dlclose(handle);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    return 0;
}
```

and my library is:

```
# cat hello-greet.cc
#include<stdio.h>
void f(){
    printf("f function\n");
}
```

When I run bazel, it gives some error:

```
bazel build hello-dl
INFO: Invocation ID: 89be69f9-5b70-4318-8b6a-43ad6feb341c
ERROR: /root/mynet/mytest/build/useBazel/cpp-project/BUILD:9:12: in deps attribute of cc_binary rule //:hello-dl: target '//:dl' does not exist
ERROR: Analysis of target '//:hello-dl' failed; build aborted: Analysis of target '//:hello-dl' failed; build aborted
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.115s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured)
```

So how can I fix this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `linkopts = ['-ldl', '-lm']` in the `cc_binary` rule.

Comment: What does it do?

Comment: Directs the linker to find `libm` and `libdl` and link them with the output executable.